# How to make a pdf report that automatically go to next page if column number exceeds the page width

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-snappy

How to automatically line-break if column numbers exceeds the page width.

Now the output showing like this
[image: Now the output showing like this]

But i want the output like this

page 1: 
[image]

Page 2:
[image]

I am using **wkhtmltopdf** and **snappypdf wrapper**.

Is there any native ways to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS.

```
thead {
  display: table-header-group;
}

tfoot {
  display: table-row-group;
}

tr {
  page-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just had to do something similar but over lines, i imagine the approach would work over columns just as effective.

first off create a css rule for pages

```
div.page   {
   page-break-after: always;
   page-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

Then split the data by the number of columns that fit on a page, lets say 20 for now.

```
  @php
   $pages = array_chunk($dataArray, 20);
  @endphp
```

Now you can loop the number of pages you need to display

```
  @for ($i = 0; $i < count($pages); $i++)
        <div class="page">
          display your tables here
        </div>
  @endfor
```

This should dynamically generate the number of pages. if its the last page you probably want to do your column endings this can be done by taking comparing

```
@if($i+1 == count($pages))
 I am your last page
@endif
```

Hope it helps and gives you an idea how to tackle this